# how to append json into a custom class array

Tags: swift

Hi I'm trying to append JSON results in to a custom array, I dont know why but I can access the data through array inside the for loop. but not outside the for loop scope. I cant get the array values into table view

Please find the the code below:

This is the class:

```
class StaitonChannel {
    var stationName: String
    var stationDescription: String
    var stationLogo: String
    var stationStreamingUrl: String

    init(name: String, description: String, logo: String, streamUrl: String) {
        self.stationName = name
        self.stationDescription = description
        self.stationLogo = logo
        self.stationStreamingUrl = streamUrl
    }
}
```

This is the Alamofire network call and SwiftyJson to drill.

```
func getTheJasonData(baseUrl: String)  {

        Alamofire.request(baseUrl, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {

                let json = JSON(response.result.value!)

                //print(json)
                if let items = json.array {
                    print(items)
                    for item in items {
                        let stationName = item["acf"]["station_name"].stringValue
                        let stationDescription = item["acf"]["description"].stringValue
                        let stationLogo = item["acf"]["logo"]["sizes"]["thumbnail"].stringValue
                        let stationStreamUrl = item["acf"]["stream_url"].stringValue

                        let newChannel = StaitonChannel(name: stationName, description: stationDescription, logo: stationLogo, streamUrl: stationStreamUrl)
                        self.channelArray.append(newChannel)
                    }
                    }
            } else {
                print("Cannot get json data from the site")
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: What is a "for loop array"?  Please be as specific as possible about the error(s) you are getting.

Comment: Not getting your point. What is the issue exactly? BTW why don't you use `struct` instead of `class`? `structs` are directly `encodable` and `decodable` with json.

Comment: "but not outside the for loop array." what does it mean?

Comment: Hi Scott Hunter, Sorry I meant for loop scope

Comment: *"cant get the array values into table view"* ... Where is the `tableView` code? I can not see you're reloading the `tableView` any where in your code. It should be just after end of `for loop`. Make sure you reload it in the main queue.

Comment: Hi The Tiger, I edited the question again, but surely I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Hi The Tiger, well I tried reloading table view in many areas it wasn't the case. when I try to print channelArray.count inside the viewDidLoad it gave me 0

Comment: *"well I tried reloading table view in many areas"* No not at many areas. You should reload once you get the data. And in your code you get the data after end of `for loop`. So in `viewDidLoad:` you don't have any data as this is an asynchronous call. Reload your table at exact same place where I said in my last comment.

Comment: The Tiger, I tried at the end of for loop, result is the same, please understand even though append in to array through the loop, array does not have any values. that is the problem.

Comment: **#1.** `self.channelArray` is `nil` or `empty`... Make sure you initialise the array before appending. **#2.** When you loop for `items` does it have any value? **#3.** Try printing the value which you are assigning yo class object and check if it has correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this and may be your are going to wrong json array or your for loop is incorrect.
SwiftyJson has given thier own method to loop into the array you can check the code below. Hope this helps

```
let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
//if array name is blank just replace json["youArrayNameInJson"] to json[""]
 json["youArrayNameInJson"].array?.forEach({ (item) in

 let stationName = item["acf"]["station_name"].stringValue
 let stationDescription = item["acf"]["description"].stringValue
 let stationLogo = item["acf"]["logo"]["sizes"]["thumbnail"].stringValue
 let stationStreamUrl = item["acf"]["stream_url"].stringValue

           let newChannel = StaitonChannel(name: stationName, description: stationDescription, logo: stationLogo, streamUrl: stationStreamUrl)
                        self.channelArray.append(newChannel)

            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Guy I found it :) it was the .stringVale should be .rawString()

```
let stationName = item["acf"]["station_name"].stringValue <-- Wrong
 let stationName = item["acf"]["station_name"].rawString() <-- Correct
```

sorry for the trouble :)

Thanks Guys